# How far away can I place the dropping resistor from a diode?

Tags: resistors, diodes

I plan to desolder the infrared diode from my raspberry-pi to add a 30cm long wire to it and solder it again. Do I need to solder the pre resistor right next to the infrared diode?

Comment: Could you specifically explain what component you're referring to?

Comment: (I want an "X-Ray diode", too, but I'm afraid such a device doesn't exist in reality)

Comment: Is there an IR LED on a raspberry pi maybe?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, there are these: http://www.osioptoelectronics.com/standard-products/silicon-photodiodes/x-ray-radiation-detectors/soft-x-ray-far-uv-enhanced-photodiodes.aspx but I don't think they're a standard option on the Pi.

Comment: Sorry, of course I mean `infrared` not X-Ray. lol
EDIT: Im also not sure about the term "dropping resistor", in german it is "Vorwiderstand" im not sure how to translate it. I mean the resistor before to the diode.

Comment: @Black Vorwiderstand: series resistor. The English word is more true to what the purpose actually is: You can have a Vorwiderstand before or after the diode, it doesn't matter, as long as diode and resistor are in series.

Comment: It more or less exists: http://amptek.com/products/cool-x-pyroelectric-x-ray-generator/

Comment: What is a pre-resistor, anyway?

Comment: As far as I know, you only need pre-resistors for z-diodes (zener diodes). It is a resistor which is in series with the z-diode, it has to be placed before the z-diode in the same direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**1. Resistor in series to fix the current**

There is no such need. The resistor will impact the amount of current in the line wherever it is.

A 30cm wire it's okay but, if a wire gets **much** longer, it will automatically increase the resistance of the line and then lower the current (due to the inner resistance of the wire). For a longer wire, you would have to recalculate the resistor's value.

**2. Pull down resistor**

There is no real difference in the placement of that resistor as well. But you just in case, put it close to the GPIO.

In any case, keep the resistor on the board. It's easier to solder than on a wire anyway

Comment: I think that the first point is a bit exaggerated... using a very thin wire (AWG30, for instance) you get a wire resistance of about 300 mΩ/m. This means that if you have a resistor of about 500 Ω, you will have a change in current of 10% if the receiver is at 80 metres from you (160 m of wire)... And in this case, use a thicker wire (AWG24 for instance will lower the drop to 1/3)

Comment: @frarugi87 Yes that's true. But just in case... Even though it's very unlikely that append